# PHP: Proper use of session in a multi-step sign up form

Tags: php, forms, session

I have made a 3-step(3 different pages) sign up process:

**First-step:** user provides basic information (name, password, gender, birthday, etc.)

**Second-step:** user provides extra information ( about, profession, interest, etc.), submit the data and gets a verification link

**Third-step:** Shows signup status( successful or failed)

I'm using the session to primarily store the information. A session variable like `$_SESSION["step_one_complete"]` tells me that the previous step was completed which is required. I've used the following code at the beginning of my `signup.php` page so that every time the `signup.php` loads the previous session data get cleared:

```
<?php //signup.php(step one)

session_start();

//Clear previous session data
$_SESSION = array();

//I'm not sure about the two lines bellow
session_destroy();
//Restart session
session_start();

...
```

Do I need the two lines I have mentioned in the code? Am I using the Session properly? Or there is a better way to handle a multi-step form? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; No, you don't. You just need to start_session, you don't need to override the session or destroy it.

Maybe i don't understand properly the question, but when you do **start_session() you enable the session in your current php script by starting a new session or resuming an existing one**. I think that in your case is all you need. Ref: [PHP - session_start](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.session-start.php)

Also, i think is bad practice to overwrite the session, you may also delete things you don't intend to. If you want to reset your variables i suggest you store them into an array like

```php
$_SESSION['form']['email']
```

and then if you want to reset make

```php
$_SESSION['form'] = array();
```

I think you can do a better job if you make a structure like this:

```php
function is_first_step_completed() // checks if the first step fields are filled or not
```

```php
function is_second_step_completed() // checks if the second step has all fields completed
```

```php
if (!is_first_step_completed()) {
// show first step
}
```

instead of storing a variable is_first_step_completed. If you use a variable like this you would need to make it true or false all the time.